# Implementing an intersection merge of 2 array lists

Tags: c#, merge

For homework assignment we have to program a Intersection merge of 2 ArrayLists. I have done it using the following code

```
    public void Intersection()
    {
        foreach (object obj1 in Developed)
        {
            Apps xApp = (Apps)obj1;
            foreach (object obj2 in DPloyed)
            {
                Apps yApp = (Apps)obj2;
                if (xApp.CompareName(yApp) == 0)
                {
                    Inter.Add(yApp);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I would like to implement it rather using the while loop but the following code seems to keep missing elements in the list. It puts the first elements in the new intersection list but once the length of developed is increased from 1 element to 5 elements or more it does not add the new elements.

```
    public void Intersection()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < Developed.Count && j < DPloyed.Count)
        {
            Apps curA = (Apps)Developed[i];
            Apps curB = (Apps)DPloyed[j];
            if (curA.CompareName(curB) == 0)
            {
                Inter.Add(curA);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if (curA.CompareName(curB) < 0)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
    }
```

Any help as to why the while loop does not work would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
while (i < Developed.Count || j < DPloyed.Count)
```

because may be both list may be having different Count.

and you need to put extra checks inside loop for indexes so that you don't get `Index out of Range Exception`.

Comment: Give me an argument was out of range exception was unhandled error on my developed[i]

Comment: Should i implement an extra while loop in my intersection method to take care of if the one list is done processing and the other not?

Comment: Ok. I'll see what i can come up with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not in the actual code for the merges. Problem found in my compare methods.